# want to send whats app like confirmation call to user through twilio api which will contain random confirmation code

Tags: php, twilio, phone-call

I am using twilio php library to send sms and voice messages to users. I am able to send message to user with the help given here 'https://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/' under "Send an SMS" section but not able to understand how to send confirmation call because in my case I am sending verification code to user.

For example I want to send voice saying this code '123456'. But this code will be random all the times. So can you please help me with this.

I have purchased plan and phone number which allows to send SMS, MMS, voice.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Rather than use Twilio's normal SMS API to do this, can I recommend you take a look at [Authy](https://www.twilio.com/authy)? Authy is a part of Twilio and provides phone verification and two factor authentication as a service.

There is a great tutorial on the Twilio site on [how to implement account verification on your site using PHP with Authy](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/account-verification/php/laravel). I recommend you have a read through this and see if it fits your needs.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for reply @philnash
I want to use twilio just to send user a call saying the confirmation code. I found this url [https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls] . Just go to the 'Example 1' you will come to know what I want.<br/>

I want to make a call let's say to 415-555-1212 and the computer will speak that 'Your confirmation code is 123456'. I am saving the confirmation code in database already. The user will pick the call and will hear the confirmation code then he will fill that code to input box on my site then I will compare that code. Hope this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 hours I found the solution. I hope this will help others and will save their precious time. Here is the complete process.

First you need to create TWIML app then assign that app to your phone number. Now create a function to make a twilio call like this

```
   function make_call{
               $account_sid = ""; // Your Twilio account sid
                $auth_token = ""; // Your Twilio account token
               $twilio_number = 'your twilio number';
               $to_number = 'number of user to which you want to make call';

                $client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid,$auth_token);
                //this is the url which twilio will hit after making a call, to get xml response which the computer will speak( if you want to send addition parameters you can do this by adding query string ). We are making here get request.
                $url = "http://test.com/say_words/?user_id=$logged_user_id";

                try 
                {
                    $call = $client->account->calls->create($twilio_number, $to_number, $url, array('Method' => 'GET'));
                    // print $call;

                    // return $call;
                    // print_r($call->sid);
                    // print_r($call);
                    $error['call_id'] = $call->sid; 
                    $error['success'] = 'You will receive a call shortly on your mobile number.';
                    // die();
                } 
                catch(Exception $e)
                {
                    // $err = urlencode($e->getMessage());

                    // print_r($err);
                    // die();
                    $error['errors'] = 'Error while makin call. Please try again.'; 

                }

             }
```

Now this is the other function which twilio will hit for xml response. If you will not create this function then twilio will make a call but will not speak anything. So create afunction like this

```
 public function say_words()
{
 $newsXML = new SimpleXMLElement("<Response></Response>");
    $newsIntro = $newsXML->addChild('Say', "Your confirmation code is $formatted");
    $newsIntro->addAttribute('loop', '3');
    $newsIntro->addAttribute('voice', 'woman');
    Header('Content-type: text/xml');
    echo $newsXML->asXML();
    die();
 }

 Twilio need this kind of xml response 
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Response>
    <Say loop="3" voice="woman">Your confirmation code is 7 0 2 8 4 6</Say>
 </Response>
```

You can check other xml responses here
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml